# Android App crashing for unknown reason

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app to the play store and it seems to be crashing for multiple users. It does not point to any specific line of code which caused the crash. The errors,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMeth 
  od (AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
  at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6308)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23969)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6816)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: before you upload on play store do you check on device or emulator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an onClick attribute in your xml and don't have a matching function for it.  Probably a typo on the function name.

Comment: So do I have to go through all my xml files and look for an onClick attribute without a matching function? No easier way to do it?

Comment: yup found it. No matching function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your fragment’s button contains onClick on XML like this:

```
android:id="@+id/button"
android:onClick="onClick"
```

And your Fragment contains this method

```
public void onClick(View view) {
// your code
}
```

But if this doesn’t work then :

Check for spelling or

implement it inside your fragment, instead of xml :

```
View button = getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // you code
        }
    });
```

Comment: I do not have any fragments, only activities.

Comment: ok, then that is spelling mistake.